# pacman -Syu - too many packages to upgrade

Tags: upgrade, manjaro, pacman

I run `sudo pacman -Syu` every day on Manjaro GNU/Linux, most of the times there are only a few or no packages to update, but like every ~7 days, it may prompts to update **hundreds** (~500) of packages, and it will take a long time to finish.
[image: pacman update prompt]
There might be 2 causes:

- I installed too many packages.
- One or more basic library packages have newer versions so all the packages depends on them have to re-compile (by the packagers) and upgrade too.

So my questions are:

- What are other possible causes for this?
- I **want to** keep my system up-to-date (always use the latest stable version of packages), but I **don't want to** cut my total installed package number **or** spend a lot of time to upgrade hundreds of packages. Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well if you installed all of those packages these are just basic updates they can be adjusted everyday depends on what maintainer does and how often it gets new fixes

Comment: Some collections of packages consist of lots of packages with the same version number that are released at the same time. One such example is KDE Applications. Since you are using Arch you don't have to compile the packages, somebody has done that for you already.

Comment: This is the weakness of a rolling release distro: If you have a lot of packages, updates will take a long time. I solved the problem by moving to a Debian testing, which has similarly many packages.

Comment: I do `pacman -S <packagename>` when I want to update only one package. I do this over a period of days to conserve data.